# duvida text files em python

Tags: python

Alguém pode me ajudar com este exercício de arquivos em python?

Considere que em cada ano há um arquivo de texto com informações sobre o mundo da população. Cada linha tem o país, a população, a taxa de crescimento da população no ano anterior, a taxa de fertilidade e a faixa etária, sendo os valores um período e dois pontos (;).

Por exemplo, suponha que o arquivo com os dados de 2016 seja denominado pop2016.txt, cujas três primeiras linhas são:

China;1403500365;0,0046;1,61;37,3

Angola;28813463;0,0342;5,88,16,5

Portugal;10371627;-0,0045;1,27;44,4

Pretende-se implementar um programa que, com o nome de um desses arquivos, um país, um número de anos e o nome de um segundo arquivo, escreva no segundo arquivo a estimativa da população daquele país nos anos subsequentes ao referido no assumindo que a taxa de crescimento permanece constante.

Se o programa receber a string 'pop2016.txt', a string 'Angola', o número 3 e a string 'Angola2016-3.txt', escreve no arquivo 'angola2016-3.txt' as três linhas seguintes:

Ano 1: 29798883

Ano 2: 30818005

Ano 3: 31871981

Para entender como é feita a estimativa populacional, observe que, de acordo com o Pop2016.txt, (em 2016) Angola tem 28 813 463 habitantes e a taxa de crescimento é de 0,0342. Portanto, se a taxa de crescimento continuar, Angola terá:

rodada ((1 0,0342) × 28 813 463) = 29 798 883 habitantes em 2017 (2016+1);

rodada ((1 0,0342) × 29 798 883) = 30 818 005 habitantes em 2018 (2016+2);

rodada ((1 0,0342) × 30 818 005) = 31 871 981 habitantes em 2019 (2016+3).

Para resolver este exercicio primeiro estou a tentar fazer um programa que le o ficheiro em nomeFich e retorna a informacao relativa ao pais indicado em pais

```
def leFich(nomeFich,pais):
    fich = open(nomeFich)
    a = 0
    text = fich.readlines()
    fich.close()
    for linha in text:
        linha = linha.split(';')
        if str(linha[1]) == pais:
            a = text[1]
return a
```

Ao chamar `leFich('pop2016.txt','Angola')` apenas me aparece 
0, que nao é o resultado pedido. Como é que resolvo este problema?

Comment: "_le o ficheiro em nomeFich e retorna a informacao relativa ao pais indicado em pais_" Você quer retornar toda a linha referente ao país?

Comment: sim, é isso que quero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> estou a tentar fazer um programa que le o ficheiro em nomeFich e retorna a informacao relativa ao pais indicado em pais

1. Geralmente usa-se underlines para nomear variáveis no Python. Recomendo que você use este padrão.
2. Sempre que possível, utilize o `with` para lidar com arquivos, assim o próprio Python chama o `close` automaticamente.
3. Índices começam em `0`, não em `1`, então aquele seu `if` deveria estar `linha[0]` e não `linha[1]`.
4. Você não precisa da variável `a`, e, além disso, esse é um nome ruim para a variável pois não é descritivo.

```py
def ler_ficheiro(caminho_arquivo, pais):
    with open(caminho_arquivo) as arquivo:
        linhas = arquivo.readlines()

    for linha in linhas:
        campos = linha.split(';')

        if campos[0] == pais:
            return linha

    raise Exception(f'{pais} não foi encontrado em {caminho_arquivo}')
```

Referências:

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names
- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Obrigado, foi uma distracao ter posto linha[1]. Mas em relacao ao teu codigo porque é que não devia ser str(linha[0]) == pais, ja que pais ira ser uma string?

Comment: @stream Você não precisa transformar `linha[0]` numa string porque isso já é uma string.

Comment: ok, obrigado ja percebi